# Phoenix - Using Brunch with jquery-validation

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, phoenix-framework, brunch

I am writing a Phoenix app and I am trying to us the 'jquery-validation' library.

I have used npm to install the jquery and jquery-validation modules. I have added both to the npm whitelist in the brunch-config.js

```
npm: {
    enabled: true,
    // Whitelist the npm deps to be pulled in as front-end assets.
    // All other deps in package.json will be excluded from the bundle.
    whitelist: ["phoenix", "phoenix_html", "jquery", "jquery-validation"],
  }
```

After starting the server with mix Phonix.server I can find both the js files concatenated into the app.js file and I have added var $ = require('jquery'); to the web/static/js/app.js file so that I have access to $.

However when I call

```
$("#form").validate({ ... });
```

in my web/static/js/app.js I get the following error in the browser console:

```
jquery.js:3848 jQuery.Deferred exception: $(...).validate is not a function TypeError: $(...).validate is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (http://localhost:4000/js/app.js:13017:16)
    at mightThrow (http://localhost:4000/js/app.js:5272:29)
    at process (http://localhost:4000/js/app.js:5340:12) undefined
jQuery.Deferred.exceptionHook @ jquery.js:3848
process @ jquery.js:3644
app.js:24 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).validate is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (app.js:24)
    at mightThrow (jquery.js:3572)
    at process (jquery.js:3640)
```

I have been unable to find any information showing how I can load a jquery library using brunch and have the methods available on the jquery object.

Any guidance greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you also show your app.js file.

Comment: Chawla thank you for following up but I abandoned it and used validation from the model files.